# Display key and value of HashMap entries in JSF page

Tags: jsf, hashmap

I would like to display `HashMap` keys and its associated value in the JSF UI.

How can I achieve this? How can I iterate over a `HashMap` in JSF page using some iterator component like `<h:datatable>`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Only `<c:forEach>` supports `Map`. Each iteration gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) instance back (like as in a normal Java `for` loop).

```
<c:forEach items="#{yourBean.map}" var="entry">
    <li>Key: #{entry.key}, value: #{entry.value}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

The `<h:dataTable>` (and `<ui:repeat>`) only supports `List` (JSF 2.2 will come with `Collection` support). You could copy all keys in a separate `List` and then iterate over it instead and then use the iterated key to get the associated value using `[]` in EL.

```
private Map<String, String> map;
private List<String> keyList;

public void someMethodWhereMapIsCreated() {
    map = createItSomeHow();
    keyList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
}

public Map<String, String> getMap(){
     return map;
}

public List<String> getKeyList(){
     return keyList;
}
```

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{yourBean.keyList}" var="key"> 
    <h:column> 
        Key: #{key}
    </h:column> 
    <h:column> 
        Value: #{yourBean.map[key]}
    </h:column> 
</h:dataTable>
```

Noted should be that a `HashMap` is by nature unordered. If you would like to maintain insertion order, like as with `List`, rather use `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: Amendments by BalusC were key to me +1 BalusC

Answer (score 1):

With `<ui:repeat>` (**JSF 2.2 and onwards**):

```
<ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{map.entrySet().toArray()}">
            key:#{entry.key}, Id: #{entry.value.id}
</ui:repeat>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/zhangsida/9206849

Comment: You can replace `value="#{map.entrySet().toArray()}` to `value="#{map}` to have the same result.