# Get HashMap value by dynamic key in EL

Tags: jsf, hashmap, el

I have a data table which contains "Package" objects and 2 columns (packageBarcode and address). I need to add a column (total number of letters in a package), but this value is not in the object. That's why, I used HashMap. I mapped the packageId and totalNumberOfLetters in this HashMap. I want to display this values in dataTable. How can I do this?

```
<p:column headerText="package" 
          sortBy="#{package.barcode}" 
          filterBy="#{package.barcode}"  
          > 
     <h:outputText value="#{package.barcode}" /> 

</p:column>
```

Comment: You forgot to show the model. Or at least, you forgot to tell where's that map in EL and where's the map key in EL. E.g. `#{bean.map}` and `#{key}`.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over a `java.util.Map<key, value>` using a `<p/h:dataTable>`? This is not supported. You somehow need to wrap entry set around a collection type such as a `java.util.List` and iterate over that collection instead. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14343788/1391249) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6225659/1391249).

Answer (score 4):

Provided a

```
private List<Package> packages;
private Map<Long, Integer> totalNumberOfLettersByPackageId;
```

you can access it as below

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.packages}" var="_package">
    <h:column>#{bean.totalNumberOfLettersByPackageId[_package.id]}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Do note that I prefixed `package` with `_`, because `package` is a Java literal and a sane EL implementation would throw a runtime exception on that.